# nscd database seems to be corrupted

Tags: linux, ldap

The nscd database in the server seems to be corrupted and user accounts authentication from ldap stop working. I can temporarily fix it by removing files in /var/db/nscd directory and restart the nscd daemon,  but the issue reoccur after 1-2 days.

Comment: Which operating system? Which daemon? Which LDAP server? You really should give more details here.

Answer (score 0):

The SElinux is active?
If yes, do you see anything in the logs about nscd?
If selinux is enabled, try this:

setsebool nscd_disable_trans true